# Identify this programmable thermostat?

Tags: thermostat

A tenant in my rental home had the programmable thermostat shown below installed by an electrician friend. Unfortunately, neither the tenant nor the friend has its instructions and can't remember where it was purchased. I've taken it apart and can find no branding on the outside cover or on the circuit board. I can't identify it by scanning through Google images. Can someone identify this thermostat so I can track down an owner/operator manual? Thank you!

[image: Unidentifed Thermostat]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a Braeburn 5400 thermostat, or a knock off of a Braeburn 5400.

[5300-5400%20Tri-Fold.pdf](http://www.braeburnonline.com/sites/braeburn/files/products/literature/5300-5400%20Tri-Fold.pdf)

[5400%20User%20Manual_0.pdf](http://braeburnonline.com/sites/braeburn/files/products/manuals/5400%20User%20Manual_0.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Your Google-fu is strong !!

Comment: Strong possibility of knock-off if the OP didn't notice the obvious branding and website on the inside panel shown in your picture.  Good find!